# Append function not working when dropdown has more than 5 dynamic options

Tags: jquery, append

**UPDATE: I Figured It Out...**
The problem was with those entries that had an apostrophe ('). Now trying to figure out how to alleviate this

---

I have a jquery script that allows me to append/"add more" rows within my **CODEIGNITER** form. One of the dropdown options within that row has dynamic data options being brought in from a separate table.

For some reason, if there are more than 5 options pulled in the "add more" button will not work and the function will not add another row.

****Don't know if it matters, but I have another dropdown section in this same form above this section and IT WORKS with more than 5 dynamic dropdown options.**

**This is really weird because more than 5 hard coded works, so I don't understand why more that 5 dynamic will not work...****

```
   <div class="table-responsive">  
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="condoms" style="width:100%"> 
                  <tr>
                    <th width="50%">Name of Distribution Site</th>
                    <th width="20%">Site Type</th>
                    <th width="15%">Zip Code</th>
                    <th width="15%">Total Condoms Distributed</th>
                    <th width="5%"> &nbsp; </th>
                  </tr>
                  
                  <!-- APPEND -->
                    <tr>  
                        <!--td><input type="text" name="con[0][condom_site]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list"  /></td-->
                      
                        <td><select name="con[0][condom_site]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" >
                            <option value="NA">Choose</option>
                            <?php foreach($con_dist_list as $con_dist) : ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $con_dist->condom_site; ?>"><?php echo $con_dist->condom_site; ?></option>
                           <?php endforeach; ?>
                          </select></td>
                      
                        <td><select name="con[0][condom_site_type]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" >
                            <option value="NA">Choose</option>
                            <option value="Adult Entertainment Venue">Adult Entertainment Venue</option>
                            <option value="Bar/Nightclub">Bar/Nightclub</option>
                            <option value="Barbershop/Hair and Nail Salons">Barbershop/Hair and Nail Salons</option>
                            <option value="Bath House/Sex Club">Bath House/Sex Club</option>
                            <option value="College/University">College/University</option>
                            <option value="Community Health Center">Community Health Center</option>
                            <option value="Faith-based Organization">Faith-based Organization</option>
                            <option value="FQHC">FQHC</option>
                            <option value="Gay-specific Venue">Gay-specific Venue</option>
                            <option value="Health Department">Health Department</option>
                            <option value="Health Fair">Health Fair</option>
                            <option value="High School/Middle School">High School/Middle School</option>
                            <option value="Hospital">Hospital</option>
                            <option value="Hotel/Motel">Hotel/Motel</option>
                            <option value="Maternal Program">Maternal Program</option>
                            <option value="MH/SA Treatment Center">MH/SA Treatment Center</option>
                            <option value="Prison/Jail/Detention Center">Prison/Jail/Detention Center</option>
                            <option value="Private Party">Private Party</option>
                            <option value="Public Sex Venue">Public Sex Venue</option>
                            <option value="Street Outreach">Street Outreach</option>
                            <option value="Taxi/Uber service">Taxi/Uber service</option>
                            <option value="Other non-traditional Venue">Other non-traditional Venue</option>
                          </select></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="con[0][condom_site_zip]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list"  /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="con[0][condom_dist]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list"  /></td>
                      
                        <td><button type="button" name="add_con" id="add_con" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>  
                    </tr>  
                  <!-- APPEND -->
                  
                </table>  
            </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){      
      var i=1;  
   
      $('#add_con').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#condoms').append('<tr id="add_con-row'+i+'" class="dynamic-added"> 
<td><select name="con['+i+'][condom_site]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" >
<option value="NA">Choose</option>
<?php foreach($con_dist_list as $con_dist) : ?>
<option value="<?php echo $con_dist->condom_site; ?>"><?php echo $con_dist->condom_site; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?> </select></td> 

<td><select name="con['+i+'][condom_site_type]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" > 
<option value="NA">Choose</option> 
<option value="Adult Entertainment Venue">Adult Entertainment Venue</option> 
<option value="Bar/Nightclub">Bar/Nightclub</option> 
<option value="Barbershop/Hair and Nail Salons">Barbershop/Hair and Nail Salons</option> 
<option value="Bath House/Sex Club">Bath House/Sex Club</option> 
<option value="College/University">College/University</option> 
<option value="Community Health Center">Community Health Center</option> 
<option value="Faith-based Organization">Faith-based Organization</option> 
<option value="FQHC">FQHC</option> 
<option value="Gay-specific Venue">Gay-specific Venue</option> 
<option value="Health Department">Health Department</option> 
<option value="Health Fair">Health Fair</option> 
<option value="High School/Middle School">High School/Middle School</option> 
<option value="Hospital">Hospital</option> 
<option value="Hotel/Motel">Hotel/Motel</option> 
<option value="Maternal Program">Maternal Program</option> 
<option value="MH/SA Treatment Center">MH/SA Treatment Center</option> 
<option value="Prison/Jail/Detention Center">Prison/Jail/Detention Center</option> 
<option value="Private Party">Private Party</option> 
<option value="Public Sex Venue">Public Sex Venue</option> 
<option value="Street Outreach">Street Outreach</option> 
<option value="Taxi/Uber service">Taxi/Uber service</option> 
<option value="Other non-traditional Venue">Other non-traditional Venue</option> </select></td> 

<td><input type="text" name="con['+i+'][condom_site_zip]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list"  /></td> 
<td><input type="text" name="con['+i+'][condom_dist]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list"  /></td> 
<td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td> </tr>');  
      });
  
      $(document).on('click', '#condoms .btn_remove', function(){  
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#add_con-row'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });  
  
    });  
</script>
```

Comment: This is really weird because more than 5 hard coded works, so I don't understand why more that 5 dynamic will not work...

Answer (score 0):

When the variable `i` is incremented the value changes. That is the reason you are not able to get more than 5 options. Move `i++` after the append statement.

```
$('#condoms').append.......
i++;
```

Comment: The variable is just used to increment ID values. It's not critical to the logic of the function.

Comment: I moved the "i++;" after the append variable and it still didn't work

Comment: This is really weird because more than 5 hard coded works, so I don't understand why more that 5 dynamic will not work...

Comment: Don't know if it matters, but I have another dropdown section in this same form above this section and IT WORKS with more than 5 dynamic dropdown options.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fully functional. In this code, I just added Jquery.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){      
      var i=1;  
      $('#add_con').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#condoms').append('<tr id="add_con-row'+i+'" class="dynamic-added"> <td><select name="con['+i+'][condom_site]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" ><option value="NA">Choose</option><option value="NA">Distribution Site</option><option value="NA">Distribution Site</option><option value="NA">Distribution Site</option></select></td> <td><select name="con['+i+'][condom_site_type]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" > <option value="NA">Choose</option> <option value="Adult Entertainment Venue">Adult Entertainment Venue</option> <option value="Bar/Nightclub">Bar/Nightclub</option> <option value="Barbershop/Hair and Nail Salons">Barbershop/Hair and Nail Salons</option> <option value="Bath House/Sex Club">Bath House/Sex Club</option> <option value="College/University">College/University</option> <option value="Community Health Center">Community Health Center</option> <option value="Faith-based Organization">Faith-based Organization</option> <option value="FQHC">FQHC</option> <option value="Gay-specific Venue">Gay-specific Venue</option> <option value="Health Department">Health Department</option> <option value="Health Fair">Health Fair</option> <option value="High School/Middle School">High School/Middle School</option> <option value="Hospital">Hospital</option> <option value="Hotel/Motel">Hotel/Motel</option> <option value="Maternal Program">Maternal Program</option> <option value="MH/SA Treatment Center">MH/SA Treatment Center</option> <option value="Prison/Jail/Detention Center">Prison/Jail/Detention Center</option> <option value="Private Party">Private Party</option> <option value="Public Sex Venue">Public Sex Venue</option> <option value="Street Outreach">Street Outreach</option> <option value="Taxi/Uber service">Taxi/Uber service</option> <option value="Other non-traditional Venue">Other non-traditional Venue</option> </select></td> <td><input type="text" name="con['+i+'][condom_site_zip]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list"  /></td> <td><input type="text" name="con['+i+'][condom_dist]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list"  /></td> <td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td> </tr>');  
      });
  
      $(document).on('click', '#condoms .btn_remove', function(){  
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#add_con-row'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });  
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="table-responsive">  
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="condoms" style="width:100%"> 
                  <tr>
                    <th width="50%">Name of Distribution Site</th>
                    <th width="20%">Site Type</th>
                    <th width="15%">Zip Code</th>
                    <th width="15%">Total Condoms Distributed</th>
                    <th width="5%"> &nbsp; </th>
                  </tr>
                  
                  <!-- APPEND -->
                    <tr>  
                        <!--td><input type="text" name="con[0][condom_site]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list"  /></td-->
                      
                        <td><select name="con[0][condom_site]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" >
                            <option value="NA">Choose</option><option value="NA">Distribution Site</option><option value="NA">Distribution Site</option><option value="NA">Distribution Site</option></select></td>
                      
                        <td><select name="con[0][condom_site_type]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" >
                            <option value="NA">Choose</option>
                            <option value="Adult Entertainment Venue">Adult Entertainment Venue</option>
                            <option value="Bar/Nightclub">Bar/Nightclub</option>
                            <option value="Barbershop/Hair and Nail Salons">Barbershop/Hair and Nail Salons</option>
                            <option value="Bath House/Sex Club">Bath House/Sex Club</option>
                            <option value="College/University">College/University</option>
                            <option value="Community Health Center">Community Health Center</option>
                            <option value="Faith-based Organization">Faith-based Organization</option>
                            <option value="FQHC">FQHC</option>
                            <option value="Gay-specific Venue">Gay-specific Venue</option>
                            <option value="Health Department">Health Department</option>
                            <option value="Health Fair">Health Fair</option>
                            <option value="High School/Middle School">High School/Middle School</option>
                            <option value="Hospital">Hospital</option>
                            <option value="Hotel/Motel">Hotel/Motel</option>
                            <option value="Maternal Program">Maternal Program</option>
                            <option value="MH/SA Treatment Center">MH/SA Treatment Center</option>
                            <option value="Prison/Jail/Detention Center">Prison/Jail/Detention Center</option>
                            <option value="Private Party">Private Party</option>
                            <option value="Public Sex Venue">Public Sex Venue</option>
                            <option value="Street Outreach">Street Outreach</option>
                            <option value="Taxi/Uber service">Taxi/Uber service</option>
                            <option value="Other non-traditional Venue">Other non-traditional Venue</option>
                          </select></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="con[0][condom_site_zip]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list"  /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="con[0][condom_dist]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list"  /></td>
                      
                        <td><button type="button" name="add_con" id="add_con" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>  
                    </tr>
                </table>  
            </div>
```

Comment: I tried your jquery script tag inline, in the header of the admin navigation file, and in the header of this view file, and it still didn't work.

Comment: This is really weird because more than 5 hard coded works, so I don't understand why more that 5 dynamic will not work...

Comment: Don't know if it matters, but I have another dropdown section in this same form above this section and IT WORKS with more than 5 dynamic dropdown options.

Comment: Please try placing this jQuery script tag before the end of the body tag (</body>). And if this doesn't work, please send me the link if it's on the server so I can check and fix your problem.

Comment: This is a codeigniter setup, so I guess I will add it to the end of this php file?